# Displaying two different cells in a collection view - Swift 2.0 iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm working on a "trading" application where I would like to have a static number of cells.

On load, users will see 5 cells, each displaying a label that says "Add."

When a "player" is added, that cell displays the players information, the other 4 cells still display the "Add" label. Another is added, 2 cells have player information, 3 have the "Add"

I'm having a hell of a time with this. Can anyone point my in the right direction? I have custom labels setup, I think my logic may just be off on how to perform this correctly.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?  What part are you having difficulty with exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to subclass the **UICollectionViewDelegate** and **UICollectionViewDataSource** protocols in your viewController, then you need to implement the *numberOfItemsInSection* and *cellForItemAtIndexPath* functions. 
Additionally to that you need to create two type of cells in your storyboard and subclass them, in the following code i will suppose that you call *AddedPlayerCell* and *DefaultCell* your cells, i will suppose that each cell has a label called *labelText* too.

```
let players = ["Player1","Player2"] //players added till now
let numberOfCells = 5

//Here you set the number of cell in your collectionView    
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return max(players.count,numberOfCells);
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            if((indexPath.row + 1) < self.players.count){ //If index of cell is less than the number of players then display the player

                    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("yourIdentifierForAddedPlayerCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AddedPlayerCell
                    cell.labelText.text = self.players[indexPath.row] //Display player
                    return cell;

            }else{//Else display DefaultCell
                    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("yourIdentifierForDefaultCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DefaultCell
                    cell.labelText.text = "Add"
                    return cell;
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to manage two different cell types, you can:

1. Create 2 prototype cells for your collection view.  Give one the identifier `"Add"` and the other `"Info"`.  The `"Add"` cell prototype will contain the label `"Add"`, and the `"Info"` cell prototype will contain fields to display the player info.
2. Add an array property to your class which keeps track of which cells are displaying "Add".
       `var showingAdd = [true, true, true, true, true]`
3. In `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, check the `showingAdd` array to determine which identifier to use when dequeueing the cell:

   ```
   let identifier = showingAdd[indexPath.row] ? "Add" : "Info"
   let cell = dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifer(identifier...)

   if !showingAdd[indexPath.row] {
       // configure the cell with the proper player info
       // retrieve info from info property array item created in
       // step 4.
       let player = playerInfo[indexPath.row]
       cell.playerName = player.name
       ...
   }
   ```
4. When a cell is selected in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`, check if it is showing add and then process it accordingly:

   ```
   if showingAdd[indexPath.row] {
       // query user to get player info
       // store the info in a property array indexed by `indexPath.row`
       playerInfo[indexPath.row] = PlayerInfo(name: name, ...)

       showingAdd[indexPath.row] = false

       // trigger a reload for this item
       collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])
   }
   ```

Comment: This is a super interesting way of doing this, I find it fascinating.